# dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib Reason: image not found

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, machine-learning, svmlight

I am getting the following issue:

`/Users/luke/Desktop/trainHOG/trainhog ; exit;
dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/luke/Desktop/trainHOG/trainhog
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
logout`

I am using a Mac running OSX v10.9.5 with openCV 3.0 alpha.

The library in question is definitely in the folder. I have tried deleting it and pasting it back into the folder, I have completely deleted and reinstalled openCV and macports, and I have tried the `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = "path to dynamic libs here.."`, but nothing has worked. I have even rebooted my computer on several occasions!

Does anyone have any further suggestions? I am out of ideas

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV 3.3
OSX 10.13
fist have a test, you can use clang++ -o a -I ./include -L ./lib 
-lopencv_core.your.version
then you can generate executable file a ,run it ,if have the error massage.
you will find the error reason cannot find the lib when you are link.

if you want to solve error on terminal
you can use **export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=your/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH**
if you want to solve error on Xcode
in build page , go to **"Runpath Search Paths"**
add you lib path

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = "path to dynamic libs here.."
```

is it applied to the environment of your program?
You can check the environment variables of a running process with

```
ps -p <pid> -wwwE
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

If you are having this Problem:

> dyld: Library not loaded: *.dylib ... Reason: no suitable image found.

Means your *.dylib files are not signed with your Apple iD develop account, and
There is two ways to solve that:

1) The right way:  Code sign all your files with errors with this command:

```
codesign -f -s "Mac Developer: YOURDEVELOPEREMAIL" /usr/local/opt/*/lib/*.dylib
```

2) The temporary way(until you don't deploy to App Store): Inside Xcode, go to:

`[YourProjectFile]` --> `[YourTargetFile]` --> `"Signing & Capabilities"` --> and Enable `"Disable Library Validation"`

Done :D

Comment: Option 1 worked for me although I needed to use my email address as the identity parameter without the "Mac Developer:" bit. I'm guessing because it was a different kind of profile.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in some versions of OpenCV's CMake configuration files which incorrectly record relative paths in the installed dylibs, reasonably easy to fix.

[This answer on answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4134/cmake-install_name_tool-absolute-path-for-library-on-mac-osx/) addresses the issue. In `OpenCVModule.cmake` and every instance of `CMakeLists.txt` replace `INSTALL_NAME_DIR lib` with `INSTALL_NAME_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Installing 3.0 still yields dylibs with absolute references.