# qt5 deployment with opencv, how to fix the lib install paths?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv, macdeployqt

A similar problem have been partially addressed here [dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib Reason: image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978806/dyld-library-not-loaded-lib-libopencv-core-3-0-dylib-reason-image-not-found)
that lead to a solution [there](http://answers.opencv.org/question/4134/cmake-install_name_tool-absolute-path-for-library-on-mac-osx/) that do not work for me.

I use Qt 5, with openCV 3 with Mac OS X 10.10.5. 
When I use macdeployqt, this process does not have the proper paths for the openCV .dylib files. It complains with:

```
ERROR: no file at "/lib/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/lib/libopencv_highgui.3.0.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/lib/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.dylib"
```

which relates to wrong file paths, given as relative but interpreted as absolute, according to:

```
$ otool -L myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp 
myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myApp:

(...)

    lib/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    lib/libopencv_highgui.3.0.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    lib/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)

(...)
```

And of course, the app crash when it runs in a different computer, complaining about the missing libraries above.

How can I fix this given that the solution mentioned above did not work? Or how can I "better" apply the solution above in this case? (I may not have adapted them properly).

I tried 3 different installation of opencv 3: CMake, homebrew, and macports. The problem remained identical.

Comment: Another not working workaround: I tried to use static lib, using the "right click" inside the .pro file to add libraries. So I end up with, e.g:

`macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../opencv3_build_static/lib/ -lopencv_core
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../opencv3_build_static/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../opencv3_build_static/include
macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../opencv3_build_static/lib/libopencv_core.a`

Yet macdeployqt gives me the exact same error, looking for .dylib inside /lib/... This does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kind soul at work helped me to better understand how I could adapt the above solutions that use the install_name_tool. Because the above solutions did not work apply to my case, here is a script with comments that describe each step in detail. This script assumes that you have used macdeployedqt already, and that you got a .app file. This fix works with opencv 3 when linking the opencv_core, opencv_highgui, and opencv_imgproc libraries. For your own case, you need to change the LIB_DIR and APP_DIR to (resp.) the directory where your opencv library files (.dylib) are, and the path to your .app package (here my app is called Qtfits_openmp). Of course, there could be a more compact script to make out of this, but I hope the detailed steps will help anyone to adapt to his/her own case.

```
#! /bin/bash

LIB_DIR=~/Dev/opencv3_tbb_opencl/lib
APP_DIR=~/Dev/build-Qtfits_openmp-clang_omp-Release/Qtfits_openmp.app
# This script supposes here that you are in the parent directory of the app.

# check to what libs your app is "explicitly" linked to with otool -L $APP_DIR/Contents/MacOS/Qtfits_openmp
# If originally linking with LIBS += -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc, you'd need to copy them in the .app with their dependencies.
# However, opencv has the path of symbolic links, ending with 3.0. , so we need to copy the actual files, i.e., with the whole version number 3.0.0. 
cp $LIB_DIR/libopencv_core.3.0.0.dylib $APP_DIR/Contents/Frameworks/libopencv_core.3.0.0.dylib
cp $LIB_DIR/libopencv_highgui.3.0.0.dylib $APP_DIR/Contents/Frameworks/libopencv_highgui.3.0.0.dylib
cp $LIB_DIR/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.0.dylib $APP_DIR/Contents/Frameworks/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.0.dylib
# Extra dependencies exist: otool -L libopencv_* will show you all the dependencies that you need to copy.
# Here we will also need to add imgcodecs and videoio to the .app
cp $LIB_DIR/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.0.0.dylib $APP_DIR/Contents/Frameworks/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.0.0.dylib
cp $LIB_DIR/libopencv_videoio.3.0.0.dylib $APP_DIR/Contents/Frameworks/libopencv_videoio.3.0.0.dylib


# With otool -L $APP_DIR/Contents/MacOS/yourApp , look at the .lib files with a wrong path. With the following result:
#   lib/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
#   lib/libopencv_highgui.3.0.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
#   lib/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)

# we need to fix the 3 libraries core, highgui and imgproc which are given here with an incorrect relative path. 
# Note that again, opencv kept the basename of the symbolic links (ending with 3.0.dylib), not the basename of the actual files (ending with 3.0.0.dylib)
# So we have to keep things consistent with what we did above. 

install_name_tool -change lib/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.3.0.0.dylib $APP_DIR/Contents/MacOS/Qtfits_openmp
install_name_tool -change lib/libopencv_highgui.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_highgui.3.0.0.dylib $APP_DIR/Contents/MacOS/Qtfits_openmp
install_name_tool -change lib/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.0.dylib $APP_DIR/Contents/MacOS/Qtfits_openmp

# Now we need to fix the path to all the dependencies of each library file.
cd $APP_DIR/Contents/Frameworks

# Change the IDs
for i in libopencv*.dylib; do install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/$i $i; done

# Again, with otool -L libopencv_* , you will see that you need to change their paths so that your copied libraries are pointed to within the app.
# for each opencv lib that is not properly referenced, change it from the absolute or wrong-relative path to @executable_path/../Frameworks/

# fix libopencv_highgui
install_name_tool -change $LIB_DIR/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.0.0.dylib libopencv_highgui.3.0.0.dylib
install_name_tool -change $LIB_DIR/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.3.0.0.dylib libopencv_highgui.3.0.0.dylib
install_name_tool -change $LIB_DIR/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.0.dylib libopencv_highgui.3.0.0.dylib
install_name_tool -change $LIB_DIR/libopencv_videoio.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_videoio.3.0.0.dylib libopencv_highgui.3.0.0.dylib

# fix libopencv_imgproc 
install_name_tool -change $LIB_DIR/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.3.0.0.dylib libopencv_imgproc.3.0.0.dylib

# fix libopencv_videoi
install_name_tool -change $LIB_DIR/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_imgcodecs.3.0.0.dylib libopencv_videoio.3.0.0.dylib
install_name_tool -change $LIB_DIR/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.0.dylib libopencv_videoio.3.0.0.dylib
install_name_tool -change $LIB_DIR/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.3.0.0.dylib libopencv_videoio.3.0.0.dylib

# fix libopencv_imgcodecs
install_name_tool -change $LIB_DIR/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_imgproc.3.0.0.dylib libopencv_imgcodecs.3.0.0.dylib
install_name_tool -change $LIB_DIR/libopencv_core.3.0.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.3.0.0.dylib libopencv_imgcodecs.3.0.0.dylib
```